# problems installing ssl certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-1.9.2

I successfully installed an SSL certificate on my website but Chrome strikes through "https" saying there are still some resources on the website that are not secure. I made sure there's no reference to http on my webpages and also replaced the google's ajax js file with https version.  How do I find what else is unsecure on my website and make sure my website is secure for users to browse and do stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome can show you everything that it's loading for a page. This is what you could do on the OS X version, the menu locations and/or modifier keys might be slightly different on other version.

In Chrome, open up `View -> Developer -> Developer Tools`

Click on `Network`.

Hold `Shift` and click the `refresh` button.

You should see a list of every network request made for that page. Look for one that is using `http` instead of `https`.